# Is it possible to make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus use external usb storage like memory sticks?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, usb-peripherals

Is it possible to make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus connect to a USB memory stick?

I have the USB Connect. How can I do that?

Comment: It supports USB Host Mode, but the question is whether it has drivers for the stick.  I'd guess not, but you could connect it and try (I assume "I have the USB Connect" means you have a USB -> micro USB converter).

Comment: Not on the stock kernel, the mass storage drivers are missing, however most custom kernels have them.

Comment: I didn't test yet, but there's [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.android.usbhostcontroller&feature=search_result) for that. You need a rooted phone and busybox installed

Comment: @loics2 still needs a kernel with the mass storage driver, most kernels have it for micro sdcard support, as the galaxy nexus has no microsd card the stock rom kernels do not have this driver.

Answer (score 0):

If your Galaxy Nexus is rooted, install this app: [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount). Then connect your USB to a USB-to-MicroUSB cable (such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HMWQE2)), and plug the micro usb into the phone, a popup will appear asking you what application do you want to open, select StickMount. Using a file manager, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer), navigate to: **/sdcard/usbStorage/** you will find your USB files there.

Note: If your phone is not rooted, you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/ET-R205UBEGSTA). Though it is costly, you can get local cables from radio shack or so. Then, use stickmount app. Note that this works only after rooting.

P.S. Rooting is not as complex as it sounds. You are just gaining access to your own phone. In Galaxy Nexus, you can unroot as well!